# Are Apple devices really Apple centric?

Tags: ios, ipad, ms-office, keynote

I had own iDevices for years but lately it had been disappointment, today my wife wanted to open a PowerPoint presentation from her uni link. I know Safari could open it but she needed to open it in PowerPoint for iPad, upon investigating the open with, it didn't had any PowerPoint in it.

That got me thinking, is Apple really selfish on choosing how things open and is Microsoft really have a valid point when it comes to surface as they are open to what person can do as they feel like really open.

Is Apple really losing market over being too Apple Universe centric?

Comment: Powerpoint is a Microsoft application, part of the Office suite. It's available **for purchase** for Windows, Mac and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/app/microsoft-powerpoint/id586449534?mt=8).

Comment: @Tetsujin I have the suite on iOS but my question is why is it that one cannot use it from web browser.

Comment: Actually, your question as it stands isn't that at all. You could edit it so it becomes that. For the two questions it does currently contain ... 1) Of course, same as any other company & 2) Unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

The default app to open any online or downloaded file is of course going to be the Apple one that can do the task.

You can choose any other app that claims to be capable by clicking **More...** at the left of the same drop-menu.

Examples below. I don't have MS Office on the iPhone, but there are many other apps volunteering for the task...

[image]